# Isn't web.xml supposed to be included when building maven project ? NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I made a new Maven project with Netbeans. There is a `pom.xml` in which i added:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Is it normal if I don't have a web.xml in my project tree after building the project or should i treat the glassfish.xml just the same  ?

[image]

I wonder if I didn't messed up things.

Comment: what type of project did you create? maven project from which archetype? was it a webapp archetype? What project packaging is described in the pom file?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo it's war packaging | I created a web app maven project

Comment: No, it does not create a web.xml itself. You need to create one in "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE 6 made web.xml optional (traded in for a bunch of annotation-based configurations).
If maven knows that Java EE 6 is the version, then it won't complain about a missing web.xml.

You should be able to configure for the most part using annotations. For portability's sake, use web.xml IF NEEDED rather than relying on vendor-specific configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Yup I Got solution (how to create **web.xml in maven NetBeans 12.0** or later)

After making web application in maven NetBeans

**1)** Right click on **WEB-INF** Folder -> **New** -> **Other**

after clicking on **other..** a window will popup
in that choose : **WEB** folder in *category*

after choosing **WEB** on right corresponding *file type* will open

in that select: **Standard Deployment Descriptor(web.xml)**

and now u have it enjoy .....

**[My first Answer on Stack Overflow :)]**